# How do I convert from a .NET DateTime to an IronPython datetime?

Tags: .net, datetime, ironpython

I'm calling an IronPython script and passing it a .NET object that contains a `DateTime` structure.

I'm trying to use IronPython's JSON support to serialize the object as JSON.

Everything works great until I encounter the .NET `DateTime`.

How do I convert from the .NET `DateTime` to the IronPython `datetime`?

Comment: Does the very last comment help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: It was slightly helpful. I can manually pull the fields out of the DateTime and construct a new datetime, but I was hoping for an easy way. It seems like this would be somewhat common.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Anticipating that people might like to convert between these we actually make it really easy:

```
import datetime
from System import DateTime
datetime.datetime(DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 6):

As we know, the `datetime` type has the following structure: `datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]])`. So all you need is to find a way how to fulfill the required options.

`strptime` is not yet implemented (otherwise you'd have the ability to simply call `datetime.datetime.strptime(DateTime.Now.ToString(format), format).strftime(format))` in IronPython. Instead, you can use the following code (not very optimized one) for now:

```
from System import DateTime

import datetime

d = DateTime.Now

print datetime.date(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day)
print datetime.datetime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, d.Hour, d.Minute, d.Second)
```

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using.

Comment: Me too. Think we both are wating now for the next iron python release with strptime realization