# How do I convert from an IronPython datetime to a .NET DateTime?

Tags: datetime, ironpython

Literally the inverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6296841/241211), is there an easy way to get a .Net `DateTime` from an IronPython `datetime`?

Clearly, one could

- Output a string and parse it or
- Dump all the date parts into a `DateTime` constructor

but those are both messy. This doesn't work either:

```python
pydate = datetime.datetime.now()
csharp = DateTime(pydate) # Crashes, because .Net wants a 'long' for Ticks
```

Is there an easy cast or a short way to get the `Ticks` that .Net wants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that [2.7.6 has been released](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/releases/tag/ipy-2.7.6.3), you can use `clr.Convert` to make an explicit cast, if needed. There could be better ways to do this, but I'm stealing this one from [Jeff Hardy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129592/jeff-hardy) [commit.](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/commit/31f5c882b3b7ecb872b627dbbb80713f48b22298)

```py
>>> from System import DateTime
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from clr import Convert
>>> now_py = datetime.now()
>>> now_py
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 18, 28, 34, 598000)
>>> Convert(now_py, DateTime)
<System.DateTime object at 0x00000000006C [1/1/2020 6:28:34 PM]>
>>> now_py == Convert(now_py, DateTime)
True
```

`DateTime(pydate)` still crashes.

Answer (score 5):

I was fairly certain a direct conversion was already allowed, but I was wrong. I added it in [31f5c88](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/commit/31f5c882b3b7ecb872b627dbbb80713f48b22298) but that won't be available until (currently unscheduled) 2.7.6.

In the meantime the best way would be to use the `timetuple` method to get the parts:

```py
dt = datetime.now()
d = DateTime(*dt.timetuple()[:6])

# For UTC times, you need to pass 'kind' as a kwarg
# because of Python's rules around using * unpacking
udt = datetime.now() 
ud = DateTime(*udt.timetuple()[:6], kind=DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29875162/241211) gets a `DateTime` to the second. If you want to stretch the precision to the millisecond, you can use something like this:

```py
def cs_date(date):
    return DateTime(*date.timetuple()[:6] + (date.microsecond/1000,))
```